# knitr: Knitting to HTML - add a prefix to figure and table numbers

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

R Markdown with `knitr` can add a prefix (usually a letter) to figure and table numbers when knitting/compling to PDF. When knitting to PDF, the following code will do the job:

````
```{=tex}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```
````

The result will be

> Figure S1.1.

rather than

> Figure 1.1

Is there a way to achieve the same when knitting to HTML?